# how to get autocomplete to make request on input change with angular-material2

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

i'm playing with [angular material](https://github.com/angular/material2/) library. I'm trying to simple autocomplete that makes request(to fetch github repos which contains the string) after input changed.

I did this code after looking at [autocomplete example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) at demo section

Here is my code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  stateCtrl: FormControl;
  private version: any;
  nm:string='';
  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.reset();
  } 
  reset(){
    console.log('input changed...');
    this.repos = this.getRepos();
  }
  getRepos(){
    return this.http
      .get(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${this.nm}+language:javascript&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10`)
      .map(res => res.json().items.map(i=>i.name));
  }
}
```

Here is my markup

```
<md-input-container>
   <input mdInput [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="nm" (keyup)="reset()">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
   <md-option *ngFor="let option of repos | async" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
   </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

My problem here that i was forced to use "change" event to get autocomplete work each time criteria changed.

I'm sure there is more accurate way, and i will be happy to know it...

here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/otxoB0hQqN8Dv7NpTxm5?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do just as they're doing in the example you linked to: bind the input to the FormCtrl, and use valueChanges(): http://plnkr.co/edit/PHFFEKXIm9xNS2DkqP9M?p=preview

Comment: thanks! Please publish your comment as answer, i will mark it as correct